# What identityserver grant type to use for angular2 net core app with registration and mobile app?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am building an app which will have web client and mobile client. Web client will be made with .net core and angular2. There will be web api which will be protected with identity server 4.

Web client will have an option to register new user.

Architecture should be like this:
[image]

What grant type should I use for web client with angular 2 and what grant type for mobile client (android, ios) built with xamarin?

Comment: for mobile use `Offline_Access`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID Implicit Flow for the web client

Resource Owner Flow for the mobile client

Here's an example for the angular client

https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow

Comment: thanks Damien. for register i am checking the ResourceWithIdentityServerWithClient project. This means that you have to use MVC to register user with identityServer and then angular for login and get requests? is it possible to create user with angular with net core identity?

Comment: Yes, you can create an user with angular directly. You just need to provide a secure API for this and you can call the add user . Some like this: https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow/blob/master/src/ResourceWithIdentityServerWithClient/Controllers/UserManagementController.cs